# setting custom icons in tabbar for highlighted/not highlighted

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, storyboard, uitabbar

I have icons in my assets that I want to use for my tab bar, 2 for each tab (one representing not highlighted i.e just an outline, and one representing highlighted i.e all filled in). The idea is to use the outlined icons for the tabs that aren't currently selected, and the filled in one for the tab that is currently selected. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an Class for your Tabbar, for example:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for item in self.tabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem] {

        // loop through all of your elements in TabBar

        if let image = item.image {

            item.selectedImage = your Selected Image
            item.image = your base Image

        }
    }


}
```

You could store all your images in an Array containing UIImage, like:

```
let TabImages = [UIImage]()
let HighlightedImages = [UIImage]()
```

And then set them in your for each loop.

Comment: Awesome! Seems to work beautifully so far. What's the purpose of the `if let` in the loop?

Comment: To check if there is an image. Its the same like if item.image != nil (but in this case, if != nil, the image variable holds the value of item.image. You dont need that in that case, it is only if you would like to transform an existing TabBar Image.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as UITabBarController
let tabItems = tabBarController.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
tabItems[2].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "tabImage1_Selected")
```

Comment: Hi Franck; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.